# Can I know the last statement executed during debugging in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

I am debugging a C# program in Visual Studio 2015.

The execution jumps to a catch statement from somewhere inside the code in the try statement.

How can I find out the last statement executed, i.e. the one which raise the exception?

Thanks.

Comment: The _stack trace_ of the exception shows you where it was thrown.

Comment: Use the debugger, step through(F5) and into (F11) each method until you find where it is throwing an error.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at your stack trace:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("starting");
        throw new Exception("Testing");
        Console.WriteLine("unreachable");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Output:

> starting
>
> System.Exception: Testing
>      at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\dfield\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line **161**

Line 161 is `throw new Exception("Testing");`

There are probably a few exceptions (hah) to this method - such as when a `StackOverflowException` or `OutOfMemoryException` occur (I think), or if a custom exception removes or otherwise alters the `StackTrace` object on the `Exception` (I've seen this done for obfuscating the stack trace that gets returned to a client who shouldn't be able to see it).  You may also have to look at the `InnerException`'s stack trace.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a window showing stack trace. How can I open such a window?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at the entry of the `catch` block, you can inspect the `ex` variable and look at its stack trace.

Comment: Or it'll show up in the __Locals__ tab as well and you can inspect it there, or use something like `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString())` to get that in the __Output__ window

Comment: Thanks. I see it. Can I click some place to jump to the last statement?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have enabled the `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` in your exception settings. When checked, the debugger should break when the error is thrown, unchecked when unhandled.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could either set a breakpoint at each statement in your try clause or you simply use the feature offered by Visual Studio. Somewhere on the bottom(where your console usually is) there sould be a window called "Call Stack". This shows you the order in which the last statements were executed.

Comment: When you're in the `catch` block, the stack trace window does no longer show the stack as it was at the statement that threw the exception.

Answer (score 1):

When you catch the exception, look at the StackTrace value, it will give you all the information about where the exception is happening with the reason of the exception:

Example: Tried to convert a string to int using Int32.Parse("Hello"); will throw an exception and stack trace as below:

at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
   at Test123() in program.cs:line 32

Answer (score 1):

Open the `diagnostic tools` window and search for a red item in the `Events` list.

Double click on it to go directly to the line which raise the exception.

[image]